# How to access attributes of associated resource in view through Devise's user model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise

I am experiencing issues while trying to display user profile attributes in a view, using Devise. This is just to display the value, I am not even trying to update it yet, so I believe that there is no need of strong parameters.

**Here are my models:**

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

and

```
# profile.rb
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
# users_controller.rb
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
  def index
    @users = User.all.order('id ASC')
  end
end
```

**Here is my view:**

```
# index.html.erb
<% if @users.present? %>
  <p><%= @users.first.profile.first_name %></p>

  <ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li><%= user.profile.first_name %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Now while `<%= @users.first.profile.first_name %>` outside of the "each" loop works well and returns the value, `<%= @users.first.profile.first_name %>` inside the loop returns the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

I came to the conclusion that this is down to Devise and how it allows you to access any associated records outside of its own controller. For the record, I tried the same code for other resources and it worked as expected.

Any help on this would be really appreciated!

Comment: I do not believe this has anything to do with devise, the natural explanation is that there is at least one row in your `users` table that does *not* have a corresponding row in the `profiles` table. Using ActiveRecord, you could find these by doing `User.all.to_a.select { |u| u.profile.nil? }`

Comment: But of course! Thanks @gregates, I can't believe I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You loop through `users` and call `.profile.first_name`, but some of your users don't have `.profile`, ie it is `nil`, thats why you receive:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass

Simply replace

```
<li><%= user.profile.first_name %></li>
```

with

```
<li><%= user.profile.try(:first_name) %></li>
```

[`.try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) will return `nil` instead exception raising if user's `.profile` doesn't exist

Alternatively handle it yourself/show some message:

```
<li><%= user.profile.present? ? user.profile.first_name : "Profile doesn't exist" %></li>
```

Comment: Thanks @rustam-a-gasanov, that's much helpful! That makes me think that I should really introduce more conditions and fallbacks in my code.